# keytool error bash: keytool: command not found

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, certificate, keytool

I have tried to execute keytool from Java bin directory but I get an error with warning bash: keytool: command not found.

```
root@xxxxxx]# keytool -genkey -alias mypassword -keyalg RSA

bash: keytools: command not found
```

Answer (score 99, accepted):

These are the steps which solved my problem:

- Search the path where my java was installed

  ```
  find / -name jre
  ```
- Move to java directory (where jre was installed on my server)

  ```
  cd /path/to/jre/bin
  ```
- Create SSL certificate with keytool command

  ```
  ./keytool -genkey -alias [mypassword] -keyalg [RSA]
  ```

Comment: @user217929 how can we solve this problem by adding `keytool` to `$PATH` so that the command can be executed from any directory?

Comment: Add `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/jre/bin` to your `.bashrc` file.

Comment: note that the keytool is not in the jre folder, but in the bin folder

Comment: People who are facing this issue inside docker image( I faced it in logstash 7.16.1), can use RUN cd ../.. && find / -iname keytool to find the correct path of it and change it in Dockerfile. Also, these debugging steps will be applicable to cacert file.

Comment: `alias keytool=$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool`

Answer (score 20):

Use

```
./keytool -genkey -alias mypassword -keyalg RSA
```

Comment: Where will be the generated file location?

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

Answer (score 7):

Ensure jre is installed.

```
cd /path/to/jre/bin/folder
```

As keytool file is present in the bin folder of jre, give path till bin as in the command above.

Then you can do:

```
keytool -genkey -alias aliaskeyname -keyalg RSA -keystore C:\mykeystore
```

The additional option -keystore will help you to specify the path where you want the generated self signed certificate.

Answer (score 7):

find your jre location ::`sudo find / -name jre`
And then :: `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/keytool keytool /opt/jdk/<jdk.verson>/jre/bin/keytool 100`

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking for `keytool` because you are working with Android studio / Google Firebase, there is a keytool bundled with Android Studio. After extracting the zip file, the path to keytool is `android-studio/jre/bin`.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that calling `sudo update-alternatives --config java` effects keytool.  Depending on which version of Java is chosen it changes whether or not keytool is on the path.  I had to chose the open JDK instead of Oracle's JDK to not get `bash: /usr/bin/keytool: No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 3):

Keytool comes with your Java library. So you have to execute the Keytool command from your /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin directory. 
Or you can add JAVA_HOME to your environmental variables (Windows) or ~/.bash_profile (Linux)

Answer (score 2):

You tried:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java6-installer --reinstall
```

and:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config keytool
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also put this on one line like so:

`/path/to/jre/bin/keytool -genkey -alias [mypassword] -keyalg [RSA]`

Wanted to include this as a comment on piet.t answer but I don't have enough rep to comment.

See the "signing" section of this article that describes how to access the keytool.exe without changing your working directory to the path: 
https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#signing-the-app

Note that they say you can type in space separated folder names like /"Program Files"/ with quotes but I found in bash i had to separate with back slashes like /Program\ Files/.

Answer (score 1):

If the jre is installed on your machine properly then look for keytool in jre or in jre/bin

1. to find where jre is installed, use this

   sudo find / -name jre
2. Then look for keytool in path_to_jre or in path_to_jre/bin
3. cd to keytool location
4. then run ./keytool
5. Make sure to add the the path to $PATH by

   export PATH=$PATH:location_to_keytool
6. To make sure you got it right after this, run

   where keytool
7. for future edit you bash or zshrc file and source it

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using openjdk, use the below commands to set your keytool.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/keytool" "keytool" "/usr/lib/jvm/java8/jdk1.8.0_251/bin/keytool" 1
```

AND

```
sudo update-alternatives --set keytool /usr/lib/jvm/java8/jdk1.8.0_251/bin/keytool
```

This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps:

1. first set the domain using `setDomain.sh` command
   go to `domain/bin` location and execute `./setDomain.sh` command
2. go to `java/bin` folder  and execute `keytool` command.

`keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -kaysize 2048 -alias name -kaystore file.jks`